# HTML5 included Javascript document.write() doesn't work with XML file

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I couldn't get Javascript to list "start" numbers on website because it empty.

Here my html body codes,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
    x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

    for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
        document.write(x[i].getAttribute('start'));
        document.write("/n");

    }
</script>
```

then this is sample of xml codes from captions.xml

```
<transcript>
<text start="6.738" dur="2.277">and explain a few interesting points about them.</text>
<text start="9.016" dur="2.722">But first I need to crush your expectations.</text>
<text start="24.716" dur="1.611">So let&#39;s begin.</text>
<text start="26.328" dur="2.535">First we start with the solvent diethyl phthalate.</text></transcript>
```

Comment: document.wite <-- did you miss this?

Comment: Also, don't use document.write, update the innerHTML of an element on the page.

Comment: I misstype it, it still doesn't work with corrected one.

Comment: By "doesn't work" what do you mean? Does it loop? Do you get a JS error in the console?

Comment: I fixed it and it doesn't show any error on JS console on Firefox FireBug console. The site still empty

Comment: Something is wrong with your XML or how you're fetching it.

Comment: ReferenceError: loadXMLDoc is not defined

captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");

Comment: So, are you including the library on your page that gives you `loadXMLDoc` function?

Comment: Not using library, how am I going to type short code to get XML content?

Comment: If yo are not using a library, where did you get the code from that includes the function `loadXMLDoc`? You might start there and figure out how they did it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
document.wite("
")
```

you should have

```
document.write("\n");
```

Then it works with a charm here, with load function from: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_loadxmldoc.asp

LIKE THIS:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 included Javascript....</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test" charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadXMLDoc(dname)
            {
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
                xhttp.send();

                return xhttp.responseXML;
            }

            function init()
            {
                var c = document.getElementById('container');
                captionsDoc = loadXMLDoc("captions.xml");
                x=captionsDoc.getElementsByTagName('text');

                for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
                {
                    c.innerHTML += x[i].getAttribute('start');
                    c.innerHTML += "\n";
                }
            }

            window.onload = init;
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's weird... But you should be sure the whole document is loaded before trying to write too it. And it's preferable to modify the DOM-structure over using document.write(). I've edited mt answer with what works here. (Also that document.write that i initially replaced threw an error for me)